# How to download CSV file with CRLF and not LF?

Tags: php, laravel, fast-excel

I am using FastExcel to generate `.csv` templates, but it downloads it with `LF` instead of `CRLF` for the line breaks, so whenever I edit the files on Windows, and upload the file back to the server, the `.csv` formatting is messed up.

I'm not sure if it downloads it using `LF` automatically because the server is Linux. (So maybe if the server was on Windows it would have downloaded it with `CRLF`?)

How can I fix that?

Comment: If _"and upload the file back to the server"_ means FTP, then simply set the transfer mode to ASCII ...?

Comment: you can always do a `shell_exec('dos2unix <uploaded file>')` to convert CRLF to LF endings after it's been uploaded back. (assuming dos2unix is installed)

Comment: FastExcel is a wrapper for [Spout](https://github.com/box/spout), which is a wrapper for [fputcsv()](https://www.php.net/fputcsv). Unfortunately, the optional `$eol` argument is left with the default value `\n` ([code](https://github.com/box/spout/blob/master/src/Spout/Common/Helper/GlobalFunctionsHelper.php#L98)). That means you'd need to extend some classes, if it's possible to make the libraries work that way (I don't really know).

Comment: Thanks guys, I used another parsing library that has an option to choose how to parse new lines, either `\n` or `\r\n`, so I used `\n` and it's ok now. I wonder if it's using `dos2unix` to do that